# Destroy the gameobjects of an array

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an array to instantiate multiple gameobjects when the player enters on a trigger but I don't know how to destroy these gameobjects when the player exits the trigger. This is my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class SpawnDestroy : MonoBehaviour {

public List<GameObject> spawnPositions;
public List<GameObject> spawnObjects;


void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{

    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player")
    {
        SpawnObjects ();
    }
}

void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
{

    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player")
    {

    ............

    }
}

void SpawnObjects()
{
    foreach(GameObject spawnPosition in spawnPositions)
    {
        int selection = Random.Range(0, spawnObjects.Count);
        Instantiate(spawnObjects[selection], spawnPosition.transform.position, spawnPosition.transform.rotation);
    }
}

}
```

UPDATE CODE:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;


public class SpawnDestroy : MonoBehaviour {

public List<GameObject> spawnPositions;
public List<GameObject> spawnObjects;
private List<GameObject> instantiated;


void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{

    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player")
    {
        SpawnObjects ();
    }
}

void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
{

    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player")
    {

        for(int i = 0; i < instantiated.Count; i++)
        {
            Destroy(instantiated[i]);
        }

        }
}

void SpawnObjects()
{
    // (re-)initialize as empty list
    instantiated = new List<GameObject>();

    foreach(GameObject spawnPosition in spawnPositions)
    {
        int selection = Random.Range(0, spawnObjects.Count);
        instantiated.Add(Instantiate(spawnObjects[selection], spawnPosition.transform.position, spawnPosition.transform.rotation));
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently you don't store a reference to the instantiated gameobjects.

For this you can create another list and add the instantiated objects, something like this (this is a short version, you could also store them in a temp):

```
private List<GameObject> instantiated;

...

void SpawnObjects()
{
    // (re-)initialize as empty list
    instantiated = new List<GameObject>();

    foreach(GameObject spawnPosition in spawnPositions)
    {
        int selection = Random.Range(0, spawnObjects.Count);
        instantiated.Add((GameObject)Instantiate(spawnObjects[selection], spawnPosition.transform.position, spawnPosition.transform.rotation));
    }
}
```

And then for destroying:

```
for(int i = 0; i < instantiated.Count; i++)
{
    Destroy(instantiated[i]);
}
```

There are other ways too. E.g. if you don't want to re-initialize the list every time, you can remove the items from the list before destroying them. In this case you need to iterate the list from back to front though. (Also, with the above, you must not try to reference something from the list if the objects were destroyed obviously, since this would raise an error.)

Another way would be to add the gameobjects as child to a certain parent upon instantiation and iterate them for destroying, something like

```
while(parentTransform.childCount > 0)
{
    Transform child = parentTransform.GetChild(0);
    Destroy(child.gameObject);
    child.SetParent(null);
}
```

Comment: Even though I like this I think there is a typo. `instantiated.Add(Instantiate(spawnObjects[selection], spawnPosition.transform.position, spawnPosition.transform.rotation));` should be `instantiated.Add(Instantiate(prefab, spawnPosition.transform.position, spawnPosition.transform.rotation));`

Comment: @Programmer I think `spawnObjects` is supposed to be a list of prefabs. If not, this needs to be changed of course.

Comment: @GunnarB. I've test it and this errors appear: Assets/0_asm/Scripts/SpawnDestroy.cs(44,38): error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for `System.Collections.Generic.List<UnityEngine.GameObject>.Add(UnityEngine.GameObject)' has some invalid arguments
Assets/0_asm/Scripts/SpawnDestroy.cs(44,38): error CS1503: Argument `#1' cannot convert `UnityEngine.Object' expression to type `UnityEngine.GameObject'

Comment: Oh, yeah, my bad. The return of `Instantiate` needs to be cast to `GameObject` by adding `(GameObject)` in front of the instantiate. I've edited that.

Comment: @GunnarB. I'm having an error because the player pickups some of the objects before exits the trigger. How can I solve it?

Comment: How is the picking up done? Or which part of the code is the picking up? If it is not in this code, I'd recommend to create a new question btw.

Comment: @GunnarB. When the player picks an object it is added to inventory and is destroyed the gameobject. I think the solution is to check from the list if the objects were destroyed on exit the trigger, but i don't know how to do it.

Comment: The error is : The object of type 'Gameobject' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it.

Comment: Well, that error says that you have destroyed the gameobject already when you try to do something with it (presumably adding it to the inventory). The code for the part where the items are actually added to the inventory is in another class I assume (on the player to be precise)? If so, you have 2 trigger exits? One in the above class and one on the player? In this case you will probably need to change this a bit, e.g. call a function on the player in the above code (in the forloop where you destroy the gameobjects and pass some info for what to add to the inventory).

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through the list to destroy each object, then create a new list where null objects are removed:

```
public List<GameObject> list;    
foreach (GameObject item in list) { Destroy(item); }
list.RemoveAll(GameObject => GameObject == null); // or do list = new List<GameObject>();
```

Note, when removing null objects from a list you need to wait for the next frame for the object to actually be destroyed and become a null object in the list, so you could clean the list in an IEnumerator function a frame later, example script below:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;    
public class ListCLeaner: MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<GameObject> list;    
    public void ClearList(){
        foreach (GameObject item in list) { Destroy(item); }
        StartCoroutine(CleanListAfterFrame());
    }
    IEnumerator CleanListAfterFrame(){
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
        list.RemoveAll(GameObject => GameObject == null);
    }
}
```

}